# Divide time periods to parts

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have time period defined as 20 hours back from now devided into smaller time segments. I need to make certain calculations for 20 hours so my @End_Date = GetDate() and my @Start_Date = DATEADD(Hour, - 20, GetDate())

```
| Start_Date          | End_date           |Group       |
| 2023-01-01 13:00:00 | 2023-01-01 20:00:00| 1          |  --desired output
| 2023-01-01 12:00:00 | 2023-01-01 13:00:00| 1          |
| 2023-01-01 10:00:00 | 2023-01-01 12:00:00| 1          |
| 2023-01-01 09:00:00 | 2023-01-01 10:00:00| 1          |
| 2023-01-01 06:00:00 | 2023-01-01 09:00:00| 1          |
| 2023-01-01 02:00:00 | 2023-01-01 06:00:00| 1          | --last input from query
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-01 02:00:00| 1          | --desired output
```

In case of last segment, which is ongoing, End_Date will be NULL so in that case I can add CASE statement
`CASE WHEN End_Date IS NULL THEN @End_Date ELSE End_Date END)` but for the first segment (marked as 'last input from query') I need to add some calculation that will insert additional row where START_DATE = @Start_Date and End_Date = Start_Date. I think that it has to be union but I don't know how to define condition. In addition, those periods are calculated for few groups

Below you can find some code:

```
CREATE TABLE tabName
(
Start_Date datetime,
End_Date datetime,
[Group] int
)

INSERT INTO table_name ('Start_Date', 'End_Date', 'Group') VALUES ('2023-01-01 13:00:00', '2023-01-01 20:00:00', '1') 
INSERT INTO table_name ('Start_Date', 'End_Date', 'Group') VALUES ('2023-01-01 12:00:00', '2023-01-01 13:00:00', '1') 
INSERT INTO table_name ('Start_Date', 'End_Date', 'Group') VALUES ('2023-01-01 10:00:00', '2023-01-01 12:00:00', '1') 
INSERT INTO table_name ('Start_Date', 'End_Date', 'Group') VALUES ('2023-01-01 09:00:00', '2023-01-01 10:00:00', '1') 
INSERT INTO table_name ('Start_Date', 'End_Date', 'Group') VALUES ('2023-01-01 06:00:00', '2023-01-01 09:00:00', '1') 
INSERT INTO table_name ('Start_Date', 'End_Date', 'Group') VALUES ('2023-01-01 02:00:00', '2023-01-01 06:00:00', '1') 
INSERT INTO table_name ('Start_Date', 'End_Date', 'Group') VALUES ('2023-01-01 18:00:00', '2023-01-01 20:00:00', '2') 
INSERT INTO table_name ('Start_Date', 'End_Date', 'Group') VALUES ('2023-01-01 16:00:00', '2023-01-01 18:00:00', '2') 
INSERT INTO table_name ('Start_Date', 'End_Date', 'Group') VALUES ('2023-01-01 14:00:00', '2023-01-01 16:00:00', '2') 
INSERT INTO table_name ('Start_Date', 'End_Date', 'Group') VALUES ('2023-01-01 05:00:00', '2023-01-01 14:00:00', '2') 
INSERT INTO table_name ('Start_Date', 'End_Date', 'Group') VALUES ('2023-01-01 04:00:00', '2023-01-01 05:00:00', '2') 
INSERT INTO table_name ('Start_Date', 'End_Date', 'Group') VALUES ('2023-01-01 01:00:00', '2023-01-01 04:00:00', '2')
```

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: Your `CASE` is a an _expression_, not a statement. Also, take a look at `COALESCE()` to simplify your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code

```sql
declare @start_date datetime =cast('2023-01-01 00:00:00' as datetime);
declare @end_date datetime =cast('2023-01-01 20:00:00' as datetime);

SELECT
  v.*,
  t.[Group]
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY Start_Date)
    FROM tabName
    WHERE Start_Date < @end_date
      AND (End_Date > @start_date OR End_Date IS NULL)
) t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      @start_date,
      t.Start_Date
    WHERE t.rn = 1
      AND t.Start_Date > @start_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      CASE WHEN t.Start_Date < @start_date THEN @start_date ELSE t.Start_Date END,
      ISNULL(t.End_Date, @end_date)
) v(Start_Date, End_Date);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/HacV2lxb)

The logic is as follows:

- Begin by filtering to the rows we want, by comparing based on our interval. Note the use of the interval comparison, this allows us to also get rows which only partially overlap.
- Calculate a row-number based on start date
- In an `APPLY`, output both the data we already have (adjusting for partially overlapping rows)...
- .. as well as conditionally an extra row of we are at the first row in the set and it does not abut the `@start_date`, outputting the current `Start_Date` as the `End_Date`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give an example. We will add the necessary rows through the connection with the auxiliary table. When n=0, we leave the original rows. For n=1, we add additional rows under certain conditions. These conditions should be described in the connection condition  `on (n=1 and <other conditions> ...)`.  This example is more to demonstrate adding rows, than calculating the values you need.

```
declare @start_date datetime =cast('2023-01-01 00:00:00' as datetime);
declare @end_date datetime =cast('2023-01-01 20:00:00' as datetime);
CREATE TABLE tabName (Start_Date datetime,End_Date datetime,[Group] int)
INSERT INTO tabname (Start_Date, End_Date, [Group]) VALUES 
 ('2023-01-01 13:00:00', '2023-01-01 20:00:00', '1') 
,('2023-01-01 12:00:00', '2023-01-01 13:00:00', '1') 
,('2023-01-01 10:00:00', '2023-01-01 12:00:00', '1') 
,('2023-01-01 09:00:00', '2023-01-01 10:00:00', '1') 
,('2023-01-01 06:00:00', '2023-01-01 09:00:00', '1') 
,('2023-01-01 02:00:00', '2023-01-01 06:00:00', '1') 
,('2023-01-01 18:00:00', '2023-01-01 20:00:00', '2') 
,('2023-01-01 16:00:00', '2023-01-01 18:00:00', '2') 
,('2023-01-01 14:00:00', '2023-01-01 16:00:00', '2') 
,('2023-01-01 05:00:00', '2023-01-01 14:00:00', '2') 
,('2023-01-01 04:00:00', '2023-01-01 05:00:00', '2') 
,('2023-01-01 01:00:00', '2023-01-01 04:00:00', '2')
;

with rankData as(
select *
  ,row_number()over(partition by [group] order by start_date) rn
  ,count(*)over(partition by [group] ) maxrn
  ,lead(start_date)over(partition by [group] order by start_date) nextStart
from tabName t
)

select 
   case when n=0 then start_date   
   else @start_date    --value for added row
   end start_date
  ,case when n=0 then 
        CASE WHEN End_Date IS NULL THEN @End_Date ELSE End_Date END
   else nextStart  --value for added row
   end end_date
  ,[group] 
  ,n,rn,maxrn
from rankData t
left join (values(0),(1))nn(n)
   on n=0
    or (n=1 and -- there conditions to add 1 row
          (  (rn=1 and start_date<>@start_date)  -- for first row of group
           or(rn=maxrn and end_date<>@end_date)  -- for last row of group
          )
       )
order by [group],start_date
```